# C++ passing a funtion returning a structure to thread-pool creates erratic results and "hangs"

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am a hobby programmer learning C++ and multi threading.
After some troubles getting started on my first thread-pool attempt.
Thanks for the suggestions I received in this forum.
I have come to a point where the principals are working.

What I am trying to achieve is to extract 20 tags from a music file (FLAC). There may be 7000 files to scan in one session.

Each extraction is a separate activity, and the end result (a future) is pushed to a vector of structures for later processing.

I use Code::Blocks 20.3 and MinGW 17.1 on a Windows 10 Pro computer.

The project compiles without errors or warnings.

With only 1 thread the app is running perfectly.

However, when I use 2 threads in the pool, the "ExtractTrackTags" function returns erratic values within the structure to be returned, and often the app "hangs".

I suspect that the structure I am passing is either not alive long enough, or it is shared among the pool of threads.
I tried to use a vector of empty structures (cleared after all files are done), but that did not help.
Also, when the number of threads in the pool is higher that the number of files I am feeding, the app "hangs".

I hope someone can help me make this work.
Thank you.

Ruud.

---Header---

```
#ifndef TRACKTAGS_H_INCLUDED
#define TRACKTAGS_H_INCLUDED
//-
#include "Threadpool.h" // .h and .cpp from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/221626/c17-thread-pool
#include <iostream>  // Required for comdef.h
#include <comdef.h>  // LPWSTR conversion
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>  // For threadID
#include <thread>  // For threadID
#include <wx/string.h>
//-
struct TagsStruct
{
    bool OK;
    wxString ThreadID;  //  For testing purposes only
    wxString PlayTime;
    wxString AlbumArtist;
    wxString Collection;
    // etc...
};
//-
std::vector<TagsStruct> ExtractMultiTags(std::vector<wxString> vwsFiles, wxString wsCol);
//-
#endif // TRACKTAGS_H_INCLUDED
```

---Extract function calling "ExtractTrackTags" through thread-pool---

```
std::vector<TagsStruct> ExtractMultiTags(std::vector<wxString> vwsFiles, wxString wsCol)
{
    // Clear existing Vector of Futures
    vTrackTags.clear();
    // Get max threads
    unsigned int th_cnt{std::thread::hardware_concurrency()};
    th_cnt = 1; // For testing purposes only
    Thread_Pool Pool(th_cnt);
    std::vector<std::future<TagsStruct>> Futures;
    for(auto &aTrack : vwsFiles)
    {
        TagsStruct TSp = TagsStruct();
        Futures.push_back(Pool.execute(ExtractTrackTags, TSp, aTrack, wsCol));
    }
    for (auto &Fut : Futures)
    {
        TagsStruct TSf = TagsStruct();
        TSf = Fut.get();
        vTrackTags.push_back(TSf);
    }
    return vTrackTags;
}
```

---Extract from track file---

```
static TagsStruct ExtractTrackTags(TagsStruct TagLine, wxString wsFile, wxString wsCollection)
{
    // Convert std::string to LPWSTR
    LPWSTR wsFileName{ConvertString(wsFile)};
    // Load the tags
    TagsLibrary_Load(Tags, wsFileName, ttAutomatic, TRUE);
    if (TagsLibrary_Loaded(Tags, ttAutomatic))
    {
        /* Extract the Audio Attributes */
        TAudioAttributes Attribs;
        if (!TagsLibrary_GetAudioAttributes(Tags, TAudioType::atAutomatic, &Attribs))
        { 
            TagLine.PlayTime = std::__cxx11::to_string(Attribs.PlayTime);
            // etc...
        }
        /* Extract the named TAGs*/
        //AlbumArtist
        std::wstring ws05(TagsLibrary_GetTag(Tags, ConvertString("ALBUMARTIST"), ttAutomatic));
        TagLine.AlbumArtist << std::string(ws05.begin(), ws05.end());
        // etc...
    }
    else
    {
        TagLine.OK = false;
        wxString msg = "\tNo tags found in:\n" + wsFile ;
        wxMessageBox(msg, _("ERROR..."));
    }

    return TagLine;
}
```

Comment: On an unrelated note, all symbols beginning with double-underscore are typically internal and private for the C++ standard library implementation. Unless documented as usable (like some common macros like e.g. `__cplusplus`) then you should never use such symbols. So please don't use e.g. `std::__cxx11::to_string` in your code, just use `std::to_string`.

Comment: Is this TagsLibrary thread-safe? If not, the api calls need to be synchronized.

Comment: @TainToTain. Thanks, great question. I have no idea. In case it is not thread-safe, how can api calls be synchronized?

Comment: @Some programmer dude. Thanks, you are right. I removed the macros. Do not know what I was thinking ;-(.

Comment: @Ruud Create a `std::mutex` and acquire it using a `std::lock_guard` in the scope where you're calling the API (the `ExtractTrackTags` method). [Here's an example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard). Note that this will effectively make `ExtractTrackTags` serialized but that's the reality if it's making calls to methods that aren't thread-safe.

Comment: TainToTain triggered me to run a test with dummy structure extraction. That runs perfectly.  So perhaps it is indeed a TagsLibrary problem. Any ideas on how to get non-thread-safe library calls to function properly? Or should I give up the idea of multi-threading the process?

Comment: Well, your ode doesn't get much from multi-threading anyway because whole task is waiting for the threads to finish (by calling `get()` for `future`)

Comment: @Ruud See my previous comment on how to synchronize the Tags lib calls with a mutex. But practically speaking, there will be no performance benefit unless you also have a significant portion of work in addition to calling into the tags library since the threads will effectively run serially while calling the library apis.

Comment: Well, even if I do not have the visioned result, it has been a very good exercise. I will stick to 1 thread in the pool in this case, so I can do some other work in parallel. Thanks to all for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HTags Tags` in `ExtractTrackTags` looks suspiciously like a global variable. If that's actually the case, then that's the cause for your issues. Reduce it's scope to `ExtractTrackTags` (so each thread has its own, isolated copy), and the issues should resolve themselves.

Comment: Wow, Thank you. That was indeed the solution. I started with that setup, but l thought I would save some time by loading the DLL and having "Tags" initiated only once. Never gave it any further thoughts. This has been a great learning experience.